# Windows Firewall to block port number 1433 all IPs except our office IP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

Our web server is Windows Web Server 2008 R2. I added a new rule in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Inbound rules.

I have successfully created a rule to block all IP addresses to access port number 1433 to our web server. It is blocking our office IP too. I have been looking for the setting where I can put our office's IP address to exception list. There is Exceptions in Computers tab but it is a list of windows user, not IPs.

Is there anyway we can add IP address to exception rule from "Block Rules"?

FYI:
I understand from this page, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755191%28v=ws.10%29.aspx, that the block rules come first and it activate allow rules.

I created a new rule to allow our office IP on port 1433 but it is still blocking us on that IP. To make sure if the rule works, I changed it to "Any IP" in allow rule, it doesn't work either.

Is it true that it blocks first and allows next?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is true, delete the rules you created, including your block all rule. Create a new allow rule and only allow traffic on that port from a specific remote IP, then specify your office IP.

Its a little bit tricky. But Windows firewall will actually blocks all traffic by default. So you just need to add the rule above.

Comment: also if i remember 1433 is a SQL Port ? You will need to delete the rule sql creates to allow all inbound traffic.

Comment: and 1434 for SQL. :)

Comment: is this not what you were looking for Jonas ?

Comment: I followed what you suggested and it is not working. Our port 1433 is accessible from any IP.

Comment: theres an implicit deny rule, can you use PoSH and output your firewall rules somehow. Im sure we can solve this for you

Comment: @TaylorGibb Thanks mate. Here is the spreadsheet I exported from Firewall Inbound Rules. Where can I find that implicit deny rule? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnGshiNTf0S4dExQcVhrZkVrM2NJRUtBcGtnZ1lEbkE

Comment: @JonasT lets take a look at your rules: firstly you have: "sql" and "sql port for 110.174.1.15" which are both disabled so delete them since you are not using them. Secondly you have a rule called "SQL Server" what that rule is doing is explicitly blocking * (read that as all) access to your server on port 1433, delete that cause you dont need it. The last rule you have have makes no sense cause your remote and local IPs cant be the same,  so delete that as well. Finally create a new allow rule specify port 1433 and leave local addr blank and specify your office ip for remote address.

Comment: @TaylorGibb is right; I added the Allow Rule but it didn't block other IPs. I checked my rules and found a general rule left there which was allowing all ports and it was overriding my SQL rule, when I removed it; my SQL rule worked perfect.